# Wercker API v3 - /builds endpoint is empty

Tags: wercker

I have a public project on Wercker : 
https://app.wercker.com/xurei/redux-api-react-switch/runs

I would like to list the builds via the API, but it outputs an empty array...
https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/applications/xurei/redux-api-react-switch/builds

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to get the last runs you have to use

`https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/runs?applicationId=:your_application_id`

which you can find out

`https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/applications/:username/:application`

In your case this link (https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/runs?applicationId=591dc80e1ff866010052b3d2)  will give you the last 20 runs you can see the rest of the options in the documentation [here](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/api/endpoints/runs)